# Jetpack compose: Relay - Translate Figma style to Jetpack compose theme not working

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, figma, android-jetpack-compose-material3, figma-plugin

I try to create Jetpack Compose app with Figma and Relay plugin,
Here is codelab link: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/relay-complete-app

and here is the Youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vBNmeiHlDHE

I stuck at the point where we Translate Figma style to Jetpack compose theme. check the below images

[image: I importing figma_styles.json file to project]

Here, I importing figma_styles.json file to project (figma_styles.json is generated from codelab link)

[image: Android studio can't import packages, and stuck at this point]

Android studio can't import packages, and stuck at this point

Comment: i think relay is dead or near dead their not progress since release last year

Comment: @marpheus no bro, It's very useful plugin. It's in starting phase. In future People will start working on Figma and Jetpack Compose.

Answer (score 0):

This might related to your firewall settings. I ve encountered the same connect question. After shut down the advanced firewall setting in Mcfree, problem solved. (But still, there's other import questions like 'could not convert node shape').